# sidebar "category" selection and showing features PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on an e-commerce site. After registration client will have an admin panel and have facilities  [image]

when client click on "inbox" it will show his "massages" and when click on "sent box" it will show 'sent massages'
but now when I click on "inbox"/"sent box" all the feature are coming on the same page .[image]

I don't want to show them on same pages .. 
for now i am using this code

```js
<div id="inboxdiv" >
                    
                    <script>
    function inbox() {
        $("#inboxdiv").load("member/inbox.php");
    }
                    </script>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sentboxdiv" >
                    
                    <script>
    function sentbox() {
        $("#sentboxdiv").load("member/sentbox.php");
    }
                    </script>
                    </div>
```

```html
<ul class='w-list'>
     <li class='w-list-item'><a class='link' href="javascript:inbox()">Inbox</a></li>
     <li class='w-list-item'><a class='link' href="javascript:sentbox()">Sent Box</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If user click on both(first `inbox` then `sentbox`) then you want to display both?

Comment: No , i want to show only what client clicking right now... If "inbox" then only "inbox" if "sent box" then only "sent box"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear previous div when new link is clicked. Check this solution:

```
<div id="inboxdiv" class="content_data">

                    <script>
    function inbox() {
       $(".content_data").html("");
        $("#inboxdiv").load("member/inbox.php");
    }
                    </script>
                    </div>
                    <div id="sentboxdiv" class="content_data">

                    <script>
    function sentbox() {
         $(".content_data").html("");
        $("#sentboxdiv").load("member/sentbox.php");
    }
                    </script>
                    </div>
```

Comment: thanks it is good for 2 features (inbox and sent box) .. But i have 20+ features.. its getting complicated

Comment: then add common class for all div and clear it before loading. Check my edited answer @sajid